# Trim and edit each line of textarea while user is typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to validate a users input into a textarea line by line while the user is typing it. Specifically, I want to remove trailing spaces and limit each line to 10 characters.

Currently, I use this jQuery code:

```
$("textarea").on('input',function(){

    var trimmedInput = $.map($(this).val().split("\n"), function(line){
        return $.trim(line).substring(0,10);
    });

    $("textarea").val(trimmedInput.join("\n"));

});
```

It works perfectly when the user is editing the last line of the textarea. However, when another line is validated by the script, the line cursor suddenly jumps to the last line (see [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8D8ca/4/)).

Is there a way to prevent the cursor from jumping? Do I need to validate the lines in a different way, or is there a way jQuery to remember where the the line cursor was and then put it back?

Comment: bit of a pain in the `$%^&` to do. What is use case? More detail the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("textarea").on('input',function(){
    var currentPosition = this.selectionStart;
    var trimmedInput = $.map($(this).val().split("\n"), function(line){
        return $.trim(line).substring(0,10);
    });

    $("textarea").val(trimmedInput.join("\n"));
     setSelectionRange(this, currentPosition, currentPosition);

});

function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}
```

Check the working [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/Z5qh2/).

Hope this helps.